# Is it possible to uninstall a module which is causing some errors?

Tags: 7, views

I have installed Views Bulk Operations but it is causing errors since it needs PHP 5.2.9 while my hosting is PHP 5.2.6.
I have no option to turn it off, it has a red cross.

How to remove this module?

Comment: Why are you using PHP 5.2.6 and not PHP 5.5?, better yet, Why are you not using PHP 7, it's [twice as fast as PHP 5](https://www.acromediainc.com/blog/increase-your-drupal-7-site-speed-php-7)

Comment: I would it if I can but I have no control over that, it is on the distant server where I am hosting my pages.

Comment: What Drupal version are you using? Does the red cross say a message?

Comment: I am using v.7.53, the red cross circle doesn't show any message. Thanks

Comment: Although it is useful to have the answers to my question, I think I will remove everything and reinstall Drupal from Scratch without this module.

Comment: yes its possible go to your database search for "config" table where your installed module will be located ,then delete that module table

Comment: Please be aware that PHP 5.2 has had no (security) updates since 4 years. Only 5.6 and 7.X are supported http://php.net/supported-versions.php. Find another host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can uninstall it, here is the easiest way-

If you have phpmyadmin access then-

You can disable a module via phpMyAdmin by login to phpMyAdmin. Then you must locate the database where Drupal is installed. Once you have done so look for the "system" table. Click and open it. Click to browse the table. Find the record for the module that is causing the problems and select the edit function. Set the status to "0" and save. So this will disable the module, now you can access your site and can easily login to backend and uninstall the module.

Comment: Ever thought [what would happen](http://www.sbs.com.au/topics/sites/sbs.com.au.topics/files/gettyimages-470309868.jpg) if another module depends on the module you just uninstalled through phpMyAdmin?

Comment: If you want to disable a module, there is a conveniently named sister function called module_disable().

module_disable(array('module_1', 'module_2', module_3));
Dependencies will be automatically be disabled. Because this will result in a non-trivial performance hit, you can set this to FALSE if you know that you want to keep any dependent modules enabled.

module_disable(array('module_1', 'module_2', 'module_3')), FALSE);

Answer (score 2):

Just to add information to Rahul Mishras post, if you don't know which command lines to use to delete the module tables from PhpMyAdmin. [Here's how:](https://www.drupal.org/node/157632)

1. See all the modules that have been installed enabled or not:

> SELECT name,status FROM system WHERE type='module';

2. See all the modules enabled:

> SELECT name,status FROM system WHERE type='module' AND status='1';

3. See if a particular module is enabled:

> SELECT name,status FROM system WHERE name='module_name';

4. Disable your module, set the status to 0 for the module name that
   you want to disable.

> UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='module_name';

And lastly, clear the cache,  just to be sure:

> DELETE FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid='system_list';

Answer (score 0):

First disable the module by going to `/admin/modules` find Views Bulk Operations and disable by uncheck marking it and click save button.

[image]

Now in the top right, click the Uninstall tab, checkmark Views Bulk Operations and click uninstall button.

[image]

Comment: Well this I know, but if you read well my question, the red cross means that I cannot disable it, it replaces the checking mark ON/OFF. Thank you for trying.

Comment: `means that I cannot disable it` because there is another module that depends on Views Bulk Operations, so you need to disable that module first, then and only then you are allowed to disable VBO. Same process when uninstalling, dependant module first then VBO.

Comment: @Ron if my answer solves your problem you can accept it by clicking the ✅ checkmark